# Create calendar events in Outlook using PHP

Tags: php, outlook

Is it possible to create calendar events in Microsoft outlook directly from a PHP web application without the client having to download an .ics file?

Comment: When you include an ICS in your mail, outlook will normally just add it to the calendar. Do you have any code example of how you attach the ICS to your mail and maybe the contents of your ics?

Comment: No, I haven't written any code yet, just doing some research for a project.

Comment: using webcal url you can include your events in outlook

Comment: When I did something like this I just attached an .ICS file to my mail and outlook automagically asked the user to accept the calendar date.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from any standalone applications. See [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161088) for more information.

But **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

If you deal with Exchange server profiles, you may consider using EWS. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.